# Double Binding of variables on component.ts and html in nativescript angular not working in certain page. (Working in only login page though)

Tags: angular, nativescript

In this html component, the model gets updated as expected.

login.component.html

```
<FlexboxLayout>
    <StackLayout class="form" [class.dark]="!isLoggingIn">
        <Image src="~/images/logo.png"></Image>
        <TextField hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
        class="input input-border"></TextField>
        <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="input input-border"></TextField>
        <Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign up'" class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
        <Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up' : 'Back to login'" (tap)="toggleDisplay()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  isLoggingIn = true;

  constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.user = new User();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    this.page.backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar = true;
    this.user['email']='someemail@gmail.com';
    this.user['password']='passmein';
  }
}
```

[image]

But double binding doesn't seem to be working in other pages. It's an edit page.

html

```
<FlexboxLayout>
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <Image src="~/images/logo.png"></Image>
        <TextField hint="The make of the car" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="car.make"
        class="input input-border"></TextField>
        <TextField hint="Model" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="car.model"
        class="input input-border"></TextField>
        <Button text="Save" class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

tns

```
export class UpsertVehicleComponent implements OnInit {
  car:Vehicle;
  new: boolean = true;
  constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private vehicleService: VehicleService) { 
    this.car = new Vehicle();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.car['make'] ='check';
  }

}
```

But the output wouldn't show up on the html page. What is different here? Is there some missing module that needs to be imported into the submodule the edit component belongs to?

Comment: Yes, the nativescript forms modules has to be imported in your submodules too.

Comment: So the forms module handle the double binding?

Comment: Yes, it would. If it still doesn't, you may share a Playground Sample which could be easy to debug.

Comment: No it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing `NativeScriptFormsModule` in your module, importing it will solve the problem.